How to Prevent refreshing the page moves to login page in ionic 7
When I refresh the page ,it redirect to login everytime . How to prevent that ,I have implemented lazy loading in my project. Any help would be appreciated. Below is my code. please let me know if I have to add any further code to get clear idea. And also how does the concept of page , component and modules works in ionic.
app-routing.module.ts
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { ExtraOptions, PreloadAllModules, RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthGuardService } from 'src/services/auth-guard.service';

export const routes: Routes = [

  {
    path: 'pages',
    canActivate:[AuthGuardService],
    loadChildren: () => import('./pages/pages.module').then( m => m.PagesPageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'tabs',
    canActivate:[AuthGuardService],
    loadChildren: () => import('./tabs/tabs.module').then( m => m.TabsPageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'user-list',
    loadChildren: () => import('./pages/user-list/user-list.module').then( m => m.UserListPageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'home',
    canActivate:[AuthGuardService],
    loadChildren: () => import('./home/home.module').then( m => m.HomePageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'register',
    loadChildren: () => import('./auth/register/register.module').then( m => m.RegisterPageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'login',
    loadChildren: () => import('./auth/login/login.module').then( m => m.LoginPageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'forgot-pass',
    loadChildren: () => import('./auth/forgot-pass/forgot-pass.module').then( m => m.ForgotPassPageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'first-page',
    loadChildren: () => import('./auth/first-page/first-page.module').then( m => m.FirstPagePageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'chat-view/userId',
    loadChildren: () => import('./pages/chat-view/chat-view.module').then( m => m.ChatViewPageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'home-page3',
    loadChildren: () => import('./home-page3/home-page3.module').then( m => m.HomePage3PageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'home-page4',
    loadChildren: () => import('./home-page4/home-page4.module').then( m => m.HomePage4PageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'home-page5',
    loadChildren: () => import('./home-page5/home-page5.module').then( m => m.HomePage5PageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'home-page-list',
    loadChildren: () => import('./home-page-list/home-page-list.module').then( m => m.HomePageListPageModule)
  },
  {
     path: '',
     redirectTo: 'login',
     pathMatch: 'full'
},

  

];
const config: ExtraOptions = {
  useHash: true,
  relativeLinkResolution: 'legacy'
};
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, config )],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}

auth-guard.service.ts
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonService } from './common.service';
import { ActivatedRouteSnapshot, CanActivate, Router, RouterStateSnapshot, UrlTree } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { SessionType } from 'src/app/shared/shared/enums/session-type';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthGuardService implements CanActivate {
  userData: any;
  token: any;

  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private common: CommonService
  ) {}

    isAuthenticated(): Observable<boolean> {
      const token = JSON.parse(this.common.getJWTToken());
      // Check if token exists 
      if (token) {
        console.log("inside if isauth");
        return of(true); // Assuming token is valid, return true as Observable
      } else {
        console.log("inside else isauth");
        return of(false); // No token found, return false as Observable
      }
    }
    canActivate(
      route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
      state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree {
      return this.isAuthenticated().pipe(
        map(isLoggedIn => {
          // this.router.navigate(['/tabs/my-profile1'])
          if (isLoggedIn) {
            return true;
          } else {
            this.router.navigate(['/login'])
            return false;
          }
        })
      );
    }
}

tabs-routing.module.ts
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { TabsPage } from './tabs.page';

export const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: TabsPage,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'my-profile1',
        loadChildren: () => import('../my-profile1/my-profile1.module').then( m => m.MyProfile1PageModule)
      },
      {
        path:'group-list',
        loadChildren: () => import('../pages/group-list/group-list.module').then(m => m.GroupListPageModule)
      },
      {
        path: 'user-list',
        loadChildren: () => import('../pages/user-list/user-list.module').then( m => m.UserListPageModule)
      },
      {
        path: 'home-page1',
        loadChildren: () => import('../home-page1/home-page1.module').then( m => m.HomePage1PageModule)
      },
      {
        path: 'home-page2',
        loadChildren: () => import('../home-page2/home-page2.module').then( m => m.HomePage2PageModule)
      },
     
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class TabsPageRoutingModule {}

I have tried implementing auth-guard. when calling login api I set token to cookie and If I find token in cookie , it should not redirect to login on refresh or after I compile . It should stay on same page only.

check if the constructor of CommonService is called first, or canActivate function is called first, using console.log, then you can check if the place you set the value for this.common.getJWTToken() is called before the auth service! this will help debug the issue!
